# deploying to heroku asset pipeline Sprockets::fileNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, configuration, heroku, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to deploy my app to *Heroku*. Heroku did not load my *js* and *css* files

I ran `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`
and it still was not working.

then I ran
   `heroku rake assets:precompile`

I get this error in Heroku logs:

```
Error compiling asset application.css:
 Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'jquery.ui.datepicker'
 (in /app/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss:13)

Served asset /application-989f5e5266d9b066eb316183d7db5c77.css - 500 Internal Server Error


 Error compiling asset application.js:
 Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'jquery.ui.datepicker'
 (in /app/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:16)
Served asset /application-d81c946c6f47242e5e97de9bca4938be.js - 500 Internal Server Error
```

config production.rb:

```
config.cache_classes = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.serve_static_assets = true
  config.assets.compress = true
  config.assets.compile = true
  config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false

  config.assets.digest = true
```

IN ASSETS
application.css.scss

```
 *= require_self
 *= require bootstrap_and_overrides
 *= require jquery.ui.datepicker
 *= require bootstrap-timepicker
 *= require jquery.fileupload-ui
 *= require_tree .
*/
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require jquery.ui.datepicker
//= require bootstrap-timepicker
//= require jquery-fileupload/basic
//= require jquery-fileupload/vendor/tmpl
//= require_tree .
```

Any idea how to fix this? thanks in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I believe the issue has to do with the assets not being precompiled.

In your terminal, if you run:

```
   $ >>> rake assets:precompile
```

And then do your add and commit:

```
$ >>> git add .
$ >>> git commit -m 'Added precompiled assets for Heroku'
```

Assuming your remote is called "heroku":

```
$ >>> git push heroku master
```

It should deploy properly, without having to mess up your app.

Comment: Had a similar error due to Skrollr library, and this resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The path appears messed up `/app/app/assets/javascripts/application.js` with `/app` twice. That could cause problems.

Comment: What is the directory structure of the Rails app? Does it in fact contain a double-/apps nesting? If so, try moving the nested /app back to the top of the project.

Answer (score 0):

try this and follow steps from source

in your `application.js` add `jquery-ui`

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
```

and then try

source : https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails

Comment: With jquery-ui, when I do bundle exec rake assets:precompile it gives me: rake aborted!
couldn't find file 'jquery-ui.all' How do I source the github page you have mentioned?

Comment: did you install 'jquery-ui-rails' gem?

Comment: Hmm, heroku always said Using jquery-ui-rails (2.0.2). But I did gem install jquery-ui-rails again and then compiled again, and it ended up working. not sure why this would happend.

Answer (score 0):

If rake precompile assets does not work for anyone, i was working with a fellow programmer and asked him (he fixed it on our project, not me, I was stumped.)

He is not a native english speaker but here goes:

"I've analyzed that caused you to fail at the moment is the push to Heroku error when precompile for file jquery-ui-datepicker not found, is due to changes in the sprocket calling js and css for jquery ui version 4.0.12 with the latest rails 5.0. 0, I have now fixed by way of fixed version in Gemfile and replace calls in js and css."

Lo and behold it worked after.

Answer (score 0):

1. First clean and precompile the assets

   > $ rake assets:clean 
   >   $ rake assets:precompile
2. Update the repository

   > $ git add -A 
   >   $ git commit -m "message"
3. Push to heroku

   > $ git push heroku